# ExcelJS Data under specific date column

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I am creating an excel sheet using exceljs package in nodejs application. I have an array of headers that I've generated like this.

```
const monthsArray = arrDays.map((str) => (
   { header: str, key: str, width: 10 } // Example { header: "12-15-2021", key: "12-15-2021", width: 10}
));

let headers = [
   { header: "Name", key: "Name", width: 10 },
   { header: "Phone", key: "Phone", width: 13 },
   { header: "CNIC", key: "CNIC", width: 13 },
   { header: "City", key: "City", width: 10 },
   ...monthsArray
];
```

Now I am running an aggregate which will return me records of users and along with that I will be getting a nested object inside it which will have records of attendance on a particular day soemthing like this `createdAt: "2021-12-15T19:56:37.984Z"` and `present: true`. Now the headers I am able to print out correctly in the first row with dates on top of each column and before that the said data like name, phone, city etc. However I need to know how I can show correct attendance records under the correct column? Such that the true must be written under the column `12-15-2021` for a particular user.

Here is how I am generating excel file

```
generateAndUploadExcel: async function (worksheetName, headers, rows) {
    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(worksheetName);
  
    sheet.columns = headers;
    sheet.addRows(rows);
    try {
      var bufferFile = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
      const fileExt = "xlsx";
      const aws = new FileUploadService(
        awsConfig.accessKeyId,
        awsConfig.secretAccessKey,
        awsConfig.bucketName
      );
      const upload = await aws.uploadBuffer(
        "download-center",
        bufferFile,
        fileExt,
        worksheetName
      );
      return upload;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: guys any idea about this?

Comment: can you create a sandbox of this issue?

Comment: @Spankied too many dependencies involved. YOu may check out this image of the related file to get an idea. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McfIO-yaGIQct_bnOxilneOrWzRlGFYa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sure this looks like quite an easy problem to solve technically, but I am very confused by the question itself. Perhaps you could rephrase it and gain more useful feedback. Because honestly, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, convert the db date to the exact same format which was used to create date header (key) in order to access specific column in exceljs sheet and while adding the row just do `row['date-key']=true or false`

For e.g. `dateheader = { header: "12-15-2021", key: "12-15-2021", width: 10}`
here key is `12-15-2021` and date from DB in attendance is `2021-12-15T19:56:37.984Z`, convert this to `12-15-2021` and then just do

```
let row={}
row['name']=user.name; 
row['city']=user.city; 
row[convertedDate]=true;
sheet.addRow(row);
```